# D3 SVG to canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, ionic-framework

How can I convert d3 SVG element to canvas?

I got this working on web-chrome browser but it is not working in iOS safari:

Used this example. This example also not work on iOs safari but works on chrome desktop
Ref: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/1dd1acd35f77c1fc64863e42f4a405bb

Function for SVG to Canvas:

```
function svgToCanvas() {
          // d3.select("#aloft-canvas-container").html("");
            var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            var canvas = d3.select("#aloft-canvas-container").append("canvas")
                .attr("width", (width) * devicePixelRatio)
                .attr("height", (ceilingChartHeight + topMarginFactor + xAxisTopContainerHeight) * devicePixelRatio)
                .style("width", width + "px")
                .style("height", (ceilingChartHeight+ topMarginFactor + xAxisTopContainerHeight) + "px")
                .style("position", "absolute");
            var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
            context.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
            // Convert SVG to Canvas
            // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas
            var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
            var svgNode = d3.select("#meteo-barbs-container").node(),
            serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            // var svgString = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + serializer.serializeToString(svgNode) + '</svg>';
            var svgString =  '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + domNodeToString(svgNode) + '</svg>';;
            console.log(svgString);
            var image = new Image();
            var svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], {
                type: "image/svg+xml"
            });
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

            image.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                d3.select("#meteo-barbs-container").remove();
            }

            image.src = url;
        };
```

In iOS it is drawing only half canvas. Not sure what is happening :-(

Comment: Not sure for iOS issue, but for every browsers except chrome, you must set  absolute width and height attributes on your root svg node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of canvg library simplifies all this :-)

https://github.com/canvg/canvg

```
contents.convertSvgToCanvas = function (sourceSvgId, canvasContainerId, canvasId, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, callback) {
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var svgNode = d3.select("#" + sourceSvgId).node();
    var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    d3.select("#" + canvasContainerId).append("canvas")
        .attr("id", canvasId)
        .attr("width", (canvasWidth) * devicePixelRatio)
        .attr("height", (canvasHeight) * devicePixelRatio)
        .style("position", "absolute");
    if (svgNode) {
        var cv = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
        var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        cv.style.width = cv.width + "px";
        cv.style.height = cv.height + "px";
        cv.width *= pixelRatio;
        cv.height *= pixelRatio;
        ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
        canvg(document.getElementById(canvasId), serializer.serializeToString(svgNode));
        callback();
    }
};
```